# How to import local module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have the commands.py file with functions together with main.py.
How to import the functions from commands.py to main.py?

Comment: from "you module" import "you function"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials and documentation. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from commands import func1, func2, func3
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the main.py file, simply add:

`from commands import *`

Now all functions from commands are accessible within main.py

Comment: @bemxio Don't use `import *`, it's almost always bad practice.